# How to call a component inside a function in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to create an app using react native. Im using expo.
I ve a component named DistList, which should be repeatedly called based on the number of entries from an object. But, the component is not called when used inside a forEach

**HomeData.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView, Platform, StatusBar, ScrollView, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

import dataCovid from '../store/dataCovid.json'
import DataList from './DataList.js'
import colors from './config/colors.js'


export default class HomeData extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);


    this.state = {
      dataSource : '',
      currentTotal : 0,
      currentRecovered : 0,
      currentDecreased : 0,
      currentActive : 0,
    }
 }

fetchUsers(){
  fetch("https://api.covidindiatracker.com/state_data.json")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((responseJson)=> {
      this.setState({
       loading: false,
       dataSource: responseJson
      })

    })
    .catch(error=>console.log(error)) //to catch the errors if any
    // console.log(responseJson)
    // this.calculateCount();

}

  componentDidMount(){
    this.fetchUsers();
  }

  /* componentDidUpdate(){
    this.calculateCount();
  } */

    calculateCount(){
      console.log("cc")
      // console.log("cclen", this.state.dataSource)
      // console.log("cclen", this.state.dataSource.length)
      if(this.state.dataSource.length > 0){
        let data = /* JSON.stringify( */this.state.dataSource;
        // console.log(data)

        // if(recoveredResult == 0||decreasedResult == 0||activeResult == 0){
          console.log("inside")
        // var dataValue = Array.from(data)
        // var activeResult = data.map(activeVal => activeVal.active).reduce((nextValue, activeVal) => activeVal + nextValue);
        var recoveredResult = data.map(activeVal => activeVal.recovered).reduce((nextValue, activeVal) => activeVal + nextValue);
        var decreasedResult = data.map(activeVal => activeVal.deaths).reduce((nextValue, activeVal) => activeVal + nextValue);
        var activeResult = data.map(activeVal => activeVal.active).reduce((nextValue, activeVal) => activeVal + nextValue);
        var totalResult = recoveredResult+decreasedResult+activeResult;
        console.log(recoveredResult)
        console.log(decreasedResult)
        console.log(activeResult)

          this.setState({
            currentTotal : totalResult,
            currentRecovered : recoveredResult,
            currentDecreased : decreasedResult,
            currentActive : activeResult,
          })
        // }
        console.log(recoveredResult)
        console.log(this.state.currentRecovered)
        console.log(this.state.currentDecreased)
        console.log(this.state.currentActive)
      }
    }


    handleDataList=()=>{
      console.log("asdasd", this.state.dataSource.length)
      if(this.state.dataSource.length > 0){
        this.state.dataSource.forEach(function(element){
          console.log(element);
          return (
          <View>
          <DataList 
            state={element.state} 
            recovered={element.recovered} 
            decreased={element.deaths} 
            total= {element.confirmed+element.recovered+element.deaths+element.active}
            heading={true}
            />
            </View>
            );
      });
      }
    }


  render() {
    // console.log("erer", this.state.dataSource)
    // console.log("erer", this.state.currentRecovered)
    // console.log("erer", JSON.stringify(dataCovid) )
    if(this.state.currentActive == 0){
      this.calculateCount();
    }
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
      {/* <ScrollView> */}
          <View style={styles.containerTop}>
            <View style={styles.totalContainerOne}>
              <Text style={[styles.textStyle, styles.textTotal, ]}>Total</Text>
              <Text>[{this.state.currentTotal}]</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.totalContainerTwo}>
              <View style={styles.recoveredContainer}>
                <Text style={[styles.textStyle, styles.textRecovered, ]}>Recovered</Text>
                <Text>[{this.state.currentRecovered}]</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.decreasedContainer}>
                <Text style={[styles.textStyle, styles.textDecreased, ]}>Decreased</Text>
                <Text>[{this.state.currentDecreased}]</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.activeContainer}>
                <Text style={[styles.textStyle, styles.textActive, ]}>Active</Text>
                <Text>[{this.state.currentActive}]</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.containerBottom}>
            <DataList state="State" total="Total" recovered="Recovered" decreased="Decreased" heading={true}/>
            <DataList state="State" total="Total" recovered="Recovered" decreased="Decreased" heading={true}/>

              {
                this.handleDataList()

              }

          </View>
      {/* </ScrollView> */}
        </View>
    );
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    // width : '100%',
    // flex: 1,
    // height : '100%',
    // height: 1500,
    // flexDirection : 'row',
    // backgroundColor: 'blue',
    // alignItems: 'center',
    // justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
    // marginTop : Platform.OS === 'android' ? StatusBar.currentHeight : 0,
    // elevation : 5
  },

  containerTop: {
    // flex: 0.3,
    // height : '15%',
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height/3,
    // flexDirection : 'row',
    // backgroundColor: 'blue',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
    // marginTop : Platform.OS === 'android' ? StatusBar.currentHeight : 0,
    // elevation : 5
  },
  totalContainerOne: {
    height : '45%',
    // flex: 0.8,
    width : '90%',
    backgroundColor: '#eeeeee',
    elevation : 20,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderRadius : 15,

  },
  textTotal:{
    color : colors.totalColor,
  },
  totalContainerTwo: {
    // flex: 0.8,
    width : '100%',
    height : '45%',
    // backgroundColor: 'green',
    flexDirection : 'row',
    justifyContent : 'space-evenly'
  },
  recoveredContainer: {
    // flex: 1,
    width : '30%',
    // height : '45%',
    backgroundColor: '#eeeeee',
    elevation : 50,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderRadius : 15,
  },
  textRecovered:{
    color : colors.recoveredColor,
  },
  decreasedContainer: {
    // flex: 1,
    width : '30%',
    // height : '45%',
    backgroundColor: '#eeeeee',
    elevation : 50,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderRadius : 15,
  },
  textDecreased:{
    color : colors.decreasedColor,
  },
  activeContainer: {
    // flex: 1,
    width : '30%',
    // height : '45%',
    backgroundColor: '#eeeeee',
    elevation : 50,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderRadius : 15,
  },
  textActive:{
    color : colors.activeColor,
  },
  textStyle:{
    fontSize : 18,
    fontWeight : '700',
  },

  containerBottom: {
    paddingTop : 10,
    // flex: 0.4,
    // height:'85%',
    // flexDirection : 'row',
    // backgroundColor: 'blue',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
    // marginTop : Platform.OS === 'android' ? StatusBar.currentHeight : 0,
    // elevation : 5
  },
});
```

**DataList.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView, Platform, StatusBar, ScrollView, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

import dataCovid from '../store/dataCovid.json'
import colors from './config/colors.js'


export default class DataList extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
    }
 }
  render() {
      const {state, total, recovered, decreased, heading} = this.props;
      const testStyle = (heading)? styles.testHeadingStyle : styles.dataStyle
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.stateBox}>
                <Text style={testStyle}>{state}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.stateBox}>
                <Text style={testStyle}>{total}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.stateBox}>
                <Text style={testStyle}>{recovered}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.stateBox}>
                <Text style={testStyle}>{decreased}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width : '100%',
    flex: 1,
    // height : '100%',
    // height: 1500,
    flexDirection : 'row',
    // backgroundColor: 'blue',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
    // marginTop : Platform.OS === 'android' ? StatusBar.currentHeight : 0,
    // elevation : 5
  },
  stateBox:{
    height : 30,
    width : 87,
    backgroundColor : '#f6f6f7',
    borderRadius : 5,
    // top : 5,
    justifyContent : 'center',
    // alignItems : 'center',
    elevation : 5,
    textAlign : 'left',
    paddingLeft : 5,


  },
  testHeadingStyle:{
    fontSize : 15,
    fontWeight : '700',
    color : '#6c757d',
    textShadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50)',
    textShadowOffset: {width: -1, height: 1},
    textShadowRadius: 10,
  },
  dataStyle:{
    fontSize : 15,
    fontWeight : '700',
    color : '#6c757d',
    // textShadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50)',
    // textShadowOffset: {width: -1, height: 1},
    // textShadowRadius: 10,
  }
});
```

I am using this function handleDataList() to call the DistList.js component in forEach. But calling component is not working here. Can someone assist please.

Comment: try map instead of forEach

Comment: @Zimri Leijen, sure. But is there any problem with this code written? Can this, calling another component inside an function be done in any other way?

Comment: I think the forEach loop may be the problem, because it returns undefined, which causes it to not render anything, that's why a map should work because it would return the element(s) you want to render.

Just make sure that handleDataList returns the elements you want to render. Right now, it doesn't return anything, so it won't render anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
  {
                this.handleDataList()

              }
```

You can do this, a function inside a render, and it will render whatever the function will return, which can be some html snippet or a component.

However you need to make sure that `handleDataList()` returns something

```js
handleDataList=()=>{
      console.log("asdasd", this.state.dataSource.length)
      if(this.state.dataSource.length > 0){
        this.state.dataSource.forEach(function(element){
          console.log(element);
          return (
          <View>
          <DataList 
            state={element.state} 
            recovered={element.recovered} 
            decreased={element.deaths} 
            total= {element.confirmed+element.recovered+element.deaths+element.active}
            heading={true}
            />
            </View>
            );
      });
      }
    }
```

this will return undefined.

You may think it will return

```js
return (
          <View>
          <DataList 
            state={element.state} 
            recovered={element.recovered} 
            decreased={element.deaths} 
            total= {element.confirmed+element.recovered+element.deaths+element.active}
            heading={true}
            />
            </View>
            );
```

but it doesn't, because this return is the return of the forEach function callback, but that's not going to affect `handleDataList` at all.

```js
handleDataList=()=>{
      console.log("asdasd", this.state.dataSource.length)
      if(this.state.dataSource.length > 0){
        return this.state.dataSource.map(function(element){
          console.log(element);
          return (
          <View>
          <DataList 
            state={element.state} 
            recovered={element.recovered} 
            decreased={element.deaths} 
            total= {element.confirmed+element.recovered+element.deaths+element.active}
            heading={true}
            />
            </View>
            );
      });
      }
    }
```

should return.